# Error parameters HTTPS locust request

Tags: python, cookies, locust

I´m trying to navigate in locust with an user logged in the webpage. I want to navigate sending the cookies to the server, the process is this:

@task(1)
 request to get the cookies

@task(2) 
 login in the webpage with method post and getting the cookies again

@task(3)
 trying to navigate in my webpage with the user logged, I call to this function:

```
self.client.request(method="GET", url="index.php", cookies=self.get_cookies())
```

I send 3 params, method, url of my site and my cookies of the task 2.

In my class locust I have this:

```
host = os.getenv('TARGET_URL', "http://mywebsite/")
```

I get nothing, no exceptions in locust, no get, no post, nothing, if I remove this line it works perfect.

What can I do?

Comment: No closing parenthesis in `host = ...`

Comment: I forgot copy that. Sorry. I edit the answer again.